# Making masks with Canvas globalCompositeOperation for jigsaw puzzle game backend

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to make a backend for publishing simple jigsaw-puzzle games. The game uses 12 premade shapes as masks for making the 12 puzzle pieces. I found the excellent [Canvas global CompositeOperation tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-global-composite-operations-tutorial/), and tested it.

The application I'm making is using ajax to send each finished piece to the serverside .php-script. The user loads an image (600x400) using SSE and the app moves the original image inside `tempCanvas` according to the values of the arrays arr_x and arr_y It's supposed to happen in a for-loop:

```
function drawPieces(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context =canvas.getContext("2d");
    var tempCanvas = document.getElementById("tempCanvas");       
    var tempContext = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");
    var img_mask = new Image();
    var w;
    var h; 
    var cvd0,cvd1,cvd2,cvd3,cvd4,cvd5,cvd6,cvd7,cvd8,cvd9,cvd10,cvd11;
    var arr_data = [cvd0,cvd1,cvd2,cvd3,cvd4,cvd5,cvd6,cvd7,cvd8,cvd9,cvd10,cvd11];
    var arr_x = [0,-136,-289,-414,0,-115,-270,-415,0,-118,-288,-415];
    var arr_y = [0,0,0,0,-113,-111,-111,-124,-244,-256,-243,-241];
    var img_bg = new Image(600, 400);        

    for (var i = 0; i<arr_x.length; i++) {
        img_bg = original;
        // get the mask
        img_mask.src = "img/mask"+i+".png";

        w = img_mask.width;
        h = img_mask.height;
        console.log("w = ", img_mask.width, " h = ", img_mask.height);

        tempCanvas.width = w;
        tempCanvas.height = h;

         // Her lages maska
        tempContext.drawImage(img_mask,0,0);
        tempContext.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
        tempContext.drawImage(img_bg,arr_x[i],arr_y[i]);
        myCanvas.width = w;
        myCanvas.height = h;

        // Draws tempCanvas on to myCanvas
        console.log("tempCanvas: ", tempCanvas, " img_mask.src = ", img_mask.src);
        context.drawImage(tempCanvas, 0, 0);
        arr_data[i] = myCanvas;
        sendData(arr_data[i], [i]);                
    };
}
```

Sending the image data to the server:

```
function sendData(cvd, index){
    var imageData = cvd.toDataURL("image/png");
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST", "testsave.php", false);

    // ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
    //     console.log("index = ", index)
    // };
    ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');
    ajax.send(imageData+"<split>"+index);      
};
```

I got a button to start `drawPieces`. But I get a number of issues. Firefox throws an error:

> InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable: context.drawImage(tempCanvas, 0, 0);

But if I click the button again the loop is run and I get 12 pieces in my folder. (Using xammp for now). But the pieces are cut wrong! The app doesn't seem to load the correct mask each time the loop runs.

So I tested it without using a loop by having 12 different functions where each function is calling the next one. It worked with one function, but started messing up the masks when I added more:

```
function drawPiece0(){
    img_bg = original;
    img_mask.src = "img/mask0.png";
    tempCanvas.width = 185;
    tempCanvas.height = 145;   
     // Her lages maska
    tempContext.drawImage(img_mask,0,0);
    tempContext.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
    tempContext.drawImage(img_bg,0,0);
    myCanvas.width = 185;
    myCanvas.height = 145;
    // Tegner tempCanvas over på myCanvas
    context.drawImage(tempCanvas, 0, 0);
    cvd0 = myCanvas;
    sendData(cvd0, 0);
    // drawPiece1();
};
```

Something is absolutely wrong in my setup, but I can't figure out what it is. Someone help me please!

By the way, here is my .php-script too:

```
<?php
if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{
    // Get the data
    $imageData=$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];

    $parts = explode("<split>", $imageData);
    $imageData = $parts[0];
    $index= $parts[1];

    // Remove the headers (data:,) part.
    // A real application should use them according to needs such as to check image type
    $filteredData=substr($imageData, strpos($imageData, ",")+1);

    // Need to decode before saving since the data we received is already base64 encoded
    $unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);

    // Save file.
    $fp = fopen( "pieces/".$index.".png", "wb" );
    fwrite( $fp, $unencodedData);
    fclose( $fp );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

The problem is that image loading is asynchronous which means they load in the background while your code is continuing.

That means the images won't be ready (loaded and decoded) when you try to use them with drawImage resulting in the error. The error is indirect here though as w and h do not get valid values for the canvas which means canvas will be 0 width and 0 height which will trigger the actual error when attempted drawn.

The reason why it "works" the second time is because an image exists in the browser's cache and may be able to provide the image before it's used.

Another problem is that in your loop you are overwriting the image variable so only the last image will be used when loaded.

### Solution

The solution is to make or use an image loader before you start the loop. It's easy to make one but for simplicity I will use the [YAIL loader](http://epistemex.github.io/YAIL2-images-loader-for-JavaScript/) in this example (disclaimer: author ibid) but any kind of loader will do as long as you use a callback for the images:

```
function drawPieces(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context =canvas.getContext("2d");
    var tempCanvas = document.getElementById("tempCanvas");       
    var tempContext = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");
    var img_mask;
    var w;
    var h; 
    var cvd0,cvd1,cvd2,cvd3,cvd4,cvd5,cvd6,cvd7,cvd8,cvd9,cvd10,cvd11;
    var arr_data = [cvd0,cvd1,cvd2,cvd3,cvd4,cvd5,cvd6,cvd7,cvd8,cvd9,cvd10,cvd11];
    var arr_x = [0,-136,-289,-414,0,-115,-270,-415,0,-118,-288,-415];
    var arr_y = [0,0,0,0,-113,-111,-111,-124,-244,-256,-243,-241];

    var img_bg;

    // using some image(s) loader
    var loader = new YAIL({done: draw});

    for (var i = 0; i<arr_x.length; i++)
        loader.add("img/mask"+i+".png");

    loader.load();  // start loading images

    // this is called when images has loaded
    function draw(e) {

        for (var i = 0; i<arr_x.length; i++) {

            //img_bg = original;  ??
            // get the mask
            var img_mask = e.images[i];  // loaded images in an array

            w = img_mask.width;          // now you will have a valid
            h = img_mask.height;         //  dimension here

            console.log("w = ", img_mask.width, " h = ", img_mask.height);

            tempCanvas.width = w;
            tempCanvas.height = h;

             // Her lages maska
            tempContext.drawImage(img_mask,0,0);
            tempContext.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
            tempContext.drawImage(img_bg,arr_x[i],arr_y[i]);
            myCanvas.width = w;
            myCanvas.height = h;

            // Draws tempCanvas on to myCanvas
            console.log("tempCanvas: ", tempCanvas, " img_mask.src = ", img_mask.src);
            context.drawImage(tempCanvas, 0, 0);
            arr_data[i] = myCanvas;
            sendData(arr_data[i], [i]);                
        }
    };
}
```

Note: loading images will make your code asynchronous in nature. If the code depends on some other function right after the pieces has been drawn then you must invoke that function from within the inner one after the loop has finished.

Hope this helps. If the pieces still doesn't show correctly please set up a fiddle with the images uploaded to f.ex. imgur.com so we can dig deeper into the problem.

Hope this helps!